# Select from multiple tables with same condition, avoid ambiguity error

Tags: mysql, ambiguity, fully-qualified-naming

How can I do something like this but avoid the error `column common_reference is ambiguous`? I know it's ambiguous, I want to select from table_one all the results for common_reference there, and table_two the same.

`SELECT * FROM table_one, table_two WHERE common_reference = 42`

This is obviously not going to work, so how do I use subqueries to achieve what I need?

Comment: Are you sure you want a JOIN not an UNION? Doing a JOIN like this will result in cartesian product of results from both tables. That is rarely a desired result.

Comment: Quite possibly a `UNION`, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Mchl in the comments `UNION` was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Start with...

```
SELECT * FROM table_one, table_two WHERE table_one.common_reference = 42
```

...and continue this road:

```
SELECT * FROM table_one as T1, table_two as T2 WHERE T1.common_reference = 42
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_one.* FROM table_one, table_two WHERE table_one.common_reference = 42
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will let you know via error if there is an unresolvable ambiguity in your SQL.

If you want to reference a specific field which also exists in another table (or the same table if you're doing a join on itself), use fully qualified fields

```
SELECT * FROM table_one, table_two WHERE table_one.common_reference = 42
```

and/or table alias's

```
SELECT * FROM table_one T1a, table_one T1b WHERE T1a.common_reference = 42
```

NB: Fair warning, as Mchl noted, these are Cartesian products and not typical joins.